# Conditional probability that a randomly chosen detail was made by Y, using Bayes's theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I found the below question on the internet while working through a conditional probability questionnaire.

> An automobile plant contracted to buy shock absorbers from two suppliers X and Y. X supplies 60% and Y supplies 40% of the shock absorbers. All shock absorbers are subject to quality tests and the ones that pass the tests are considered reliable. It was found that of X's supplies 96% were reliable and of Y's supplies 72% are reliable.
>
> The Probability that a randomly chosen shock absorber, which is found to be reliable, is made by Y is:
>
> (a) 0.288 (b) 0.334 (c) 0.667 (d) 0.720

I thought I could solve this question using the Bayes theorem. But as it turns out the answer I got by applying Bayes theorem was not right as I don't find it on the options. Could someone please help me find the right solutions as the website has only provided the questions and not the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Bayes's rule should work.

$$P(Y \mid \text{reliable}) = \frac{P(\text{reliable} \mid Y) P(Y)}{P(\text{reliable})}
=  \frac{P(\text{reliable} \mid Y) P(Y)}{P(\text{reliable} \mid X) P(X)+P(\text{reliable} \mid Y) P(Y)}$$

Plugging in the given values should give you (b).

Comment: I was just about to post this same answer, maybe the OP had an issue with 1/3 equating to 0.334 :/.

Comment: @Chinny84 Ah, that never even crossed my mind! Not sure why it is 0.334...

Comment: Sorry, I had a small mistake in my calculation. I got the answer now. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be the event that a shock absorber is reliable. Then
$$
Pr(Y|E)=\frac{Pr(Y\&E)}{Pr(E)}=\frac{Pr(E|Y)Pr(Y)}{Pr(E|Y)Pr(Y)+Pr(E|X)Pr(X)}=\frac{0.72*0.4}{0.72*0.4+0.96*0.6}.
$$
The calculator says this equals $0.333333$ so choice (B)?

Answer (score 1):

$$P\left[Y\mid R\right]=\frac{P\left[R\mid Y\right]P\left[Y\right]}{P\left[R\mid X\right]P\left[X\right]+P\left[R\mid Y\right]P\left[Y\right]}=\frac{0.72\times0.4}{0.96\times0.6+0.72\times0.4}=\frac{1}{3}\sim0.334$$

Here $R$ stands for reliable.